# How do I change the column of a MySQL to have another default value?

Tags: mysql, database

RIght now the server default is 1. How can I change it to 0?

THis is currently the column:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 friend_posting | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
```

It has no foreign keys or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ALTER COLUMN friend_posting
  SET DEFAULT 0
```

This won't change existing rows of course; they will need to be explicitly updated. It only sets the default for new rows.